# Google Calendar: Event update triggers cancellation email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

I have a Rails API that sends my clients Google Calendar invites when an appointment is booked.  I've noticed a strange bug when the appointment is rescheduled.

Occassionally, I receive the "Updated Invitation" email notification as expected but other times I receive an "Updated Invitation" **AND** a "Cancelled Event" email notification at the same time.

I don't understand why the "Cancelled Event" email notification is being sent at all.

Here's my API call to Google Calendar:

```
    def update_event_on_calendar(calendar_uid, location_id: , event_id: , title: nil, start_datetime: nil, end_datetime: nil, guest_name: nil, guest_email: nil, isConsultation: false)

        # get address
        location = Location.find(location_id)
        event_address = location.address

        # format attendees
        attendee_array = []

        if guest_email.present? || guest_name.present?
            guest_attendee = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee.new(email: guest_email, display_name: guest_name)
            attendee_array << guest_attendee
        end

        # Adds an event on the office's calendar 
        organizer_attendee = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee.new(email: location.email, organizer: true)
        attendee_array << organizer_attendee

        start_datetime_rfc3339 = start_datetime.present? ? start_datetime.rfc3339 : nil
        end_datetime_rfc3339 = end_datetime.present? ? end_datetime.rfc3339 : nil
        thestart = { date_time: start_datetime_rfc3339 }
        theend = { date_time: end_datetime_rfc3339 }

        description = "Congratulations on scheduling your discovery consultation"

        event_update = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(start:thestart, end:theend, summary:title, attendees: attendee_array, location: event_address, description: description)

        begin
            event = @service.patch_event(calendar_uid, event_id, event_update, send_updates: 'all')
            sleep(6)

        rescue Google::Apis::ServerError, Google::Apis::ClientError, Google::Apis::AuthorizationError => e
            Sentry.capture_exception(e)
            return reason_for_error(e.body)
        end     

        return event
    end
```

I've also tried using the `update_event` method with the same results.  Here are the [Google Calendar API Docs](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/CalendarV3/CalendarService.html).  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you working with calendar resources to manage these events?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "calendar resources"?

Comment: Something similar to this: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1033925 . This would mean that you could be affected by the autodeclined feature in case the room or resource calendar is already booked at first and generating those responses: https://support.google.com/a/answer/9682138

Comment: No I don't believe that's the issue